# How do you handle errors from chained promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest, promise

I am building an Angular app, and have a factory that executes an XHR, and returns the promise to the controller that called it. When I get an error, it gets caught in the factory fail method but because I'm returning it as a promise, it still calls the success method in the controller. Is there a way that I can get the factory error to pass on to the controller fail method and prevent the controller success method from being called? Reason being is that I'd like to properly display success and error notifications on the client side. Am I just going about this entirely wrong?

Example factory method:

```
function add(payload) {
  return $http.post('/companies', payload)
    .then(success)
    .catch(fail);

  function success(response) {
    return response.data;
  }
  function fail(error) {
    $log.log('Company Factory XHR failed: ', error.data);
  }
}
```

Corresponding controller method:

```
function add(isValid) {
  if (isValid) {
    var payload = {
      company: vm.new_company
    };

    companyFactory.add(payload)
      .then(success)
      .catch(fail);
  }

  function success() {
    getCompanies();
    vm.new_company = {};
    toastrFactory.success("Added company!");
  }
  function fail(err) {
    $log.log('Companies Controller XHR Failed: ' + err.data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to handle the promise in the factory if you are handling it in the controller.

In the factory you want to just

```
return $http.post('/companies', payload);
```

Then handle it like you are already in your controller and you're good to go.

Using .then and .catch are functions on a promise, the way you are doing it now in your factory, you aren't returning a promise, you are returning other things after the promise is resolved. You just want to return the promise alone, which is the $http.post() function.

Edit:
To add a little more depth, this is how I setup my factories for this kind of stuff...

```
function factory() {
   var self = {};

   self.addCompany = function(payload) {
     return $http.post('/companies', payload);
   }

   return self;
}
```

Then handle it in controllers like

```
factory.addCompany(payload)
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('success', data);
  })
  .catch(function(data) {
    console.log('something happened', data);
  })
```

Comment: Duh, why make myself do extra work? Thanks for the help!